# how do i implement the following function in the code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How would I add these functions to my code? To check if the account is valid using check_account() will accept the account entered by the user and also the list current_accts. This function should return a 1 if account is valid otherwise return 0 if account is not valid.

```
accNum = int(input("Please enter your seven digit account number: "))
if accNum == 5679035:
   print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum ==  8232322:
   print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 2134988:
   print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 6541234:
   print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 3984591:
   print 'Account', accNum,'is valid'
elif accNum == 1298345:
   print 'Account', accNum, 'is valid'
elif accNum == 7849123:
   print'Account', accNum, 'is valid'
elif accNum == 8723217:
   print'Account', accNum, 'is valid'
else:
   print "Account", accNum, "is NOT valid"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need some data-structure to store your valid accounts. This could be a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
valid_accounts = [5679035, 8232322, ..., 8723217]
```

Then, you can use the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) operator to check if the input number is within the valid numbers list. By doing so, you [avoid repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
account_number in valid_accounts
```

Finally, your function became as simple as :

```
def is_account_valid(account_number, valid_numbers):
    if account_number in valid_numbers:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

And you can use it like this:

```
valid_accounts = [5679035, 8232322, ..., 8723217]

account_number = int(input("Please enter your seven digit account number: "))

if is_valid_account(account_number, valid_numbers) == 1:
    print 'Account', account_number, 'is valid'
else:
    print "Account", account_number, "is NOT valid"
```

---

Note that with Python, it is suggested to use [snake_case](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Also, as you look to be a beginner, I strongly recommend you to use Python 3 instead of Python 2.7.

Comment: I got how to check if its valid or not but it needs a function check_account () added which checks if the account is valid. It will accept the account entered by the user and also the list current_accts. This function should return a 1 if account is valid otherwise return 0 if account is not valid

Answer (score 2):

Well you should've used a list:

```
def validate(accNum, accList):
    if accNum in accList:
        return 1
    return 0

print(validate(2134988, [5679035, 8232322, 2134988, 6541234, 3984591, 1298345, 7849123, 8723217]))
```

Output: `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'Account %i %s' % (
    account_num,
    'Valid' if account_num in {
        5679035, 8232322, 2134988,
        6541234, 3984591, 1298345,
        7849123, 8723217
    } else 'Invalid'
)
```

The {} is just shorthand for a set construction.

Comment: It's a one liner, how would you propose I format it better?

Comment: It wasn't a *one-liner*! :)

Comment: It most certainly was :)  We have a print with a ternary.  Anyway, thanks for formatting it nicely.  I'll keep formatting in mind for future responses.